# Mysql Query problem in searching record

Tags: sql, mysql

Query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.ads_city,
       t1.ads_title,
       t1.ads_description,
       t1.ads_type,
       t2.ads_activate,
       t2.postads_id,
       t2.ads_id 
  FROM table_1 t1 
  JOIN nextpostads t2 ON t1.id = t2.postads_id
 WHERE MATCH(t1.ads_title,t1.ads_description) AGAINST ('LCD  projector ,' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
   AND t2.ads_activate='Yes' 
   AND t1.ads_type='offering'
```

I have 2 record first record title is

```
" LCD projector,plasma display,recording speaker products"
```

and second record title is

```
" Interactive products(projection screen,projectors,touch panel,network camera)"
```

But from the above query I am not related result what is problem with it ?

Comment: what result are you getting from this query, give some sample data

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the `t2.ads_activate` value isn't "Yes" and/or the `t1.ads_type` value isn't "offering".  Try:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.ads_city,
       t1.ads_title,
       t1.ads_description,
       t1.ads_type,
       t2.ads_activate,
       t2.postads_id,
       t2.ads_id 
  FROM table_1 t1 
  JOIN nextpostads t2 ON t1.id = t2.postads_id
 WHERE MATCH(t1.ads_title,t1.ads_description) AGAINST ('LCD  projector ,' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If the records you expect are returned, add the missing WHERE clauses ***, testing them one at a time***.  Otherwise, there's something with your JOIN...

Comment: @Ajay_kumar: If this helped answer your question, would you mind marking it as the answer?  Click the check icon, just under the number (currently zero) & arrows to the left of the answer.